# Divs not floating despite correct total width

Tags: html, css, grid, css-float

I can't wrap my head around why my 25% div is not floating next to 75%.
The widths of the divs including margins sum up to a correct total width of the .content div.
I must be missing some info on how margins, paddings and floats work together. I'd use a ready built grid system but in this case it has to be a custom one.

If someone could give a hint, it would be much appreciated.

Here's the HTML.

```
<body> 
<div class='container'>
     <div role='header'>
         <div class='row common-navigation'>
             <div class='wide' id='globalnav'></div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class='content' role='content'>
         <div class='section100'>
             <div class='component'>
                 <p>100% column</p>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class='section75'>
             <div class='component'>
                 <p>75% column</p>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class='section25'>
             <div class='component'>
                 <p>25% column</p>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ercrL/)

Comment: because of the margins: they add to the size as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class .section75 and .section25 both are adding total 10px margin on the width of each div. So either you need to reduce the the same amount from the width. Or you can apply padding instead of using margin like below.

```
.section100,.section75,.section25 {float: left; padding: 0 5px;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}

.section100 {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
width: 100%;
}

.section75 {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
width: 75%;
}

.section25 {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
width: 25%;
}
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerdeepti/ercrL/11/)

Comment: Thanks Santo!! I have added both `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;` and `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` so that it would support all browsers. Also updated the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried the sizing before with only padding on the containers but adding the box-sizing -property helped to ensure the containers really stay the width I tell them to.

Answer (score 1):

replace your margin with 0,5% instead of o,5 px

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the margin to only right. also change the float to right.

here is your css code. please replace and check it.

```
.section25 {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 24%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ercrL/1/

Because you have left and right `margins` on your `section` divs, and they weren't at `75%`, they we being set to `74% and 24%` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use margin, margin is on the **outside** of the box, while padding is on the **inside**. (margin will get added with the width)

remove

```
margin
```

from your containers

http://jsfiddle.net/ercrL/4/

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

You left some **margins** in your `CSS` code.

Margin affects the size of your **DOM element**: [W3Schools source](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

---

## Solution

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ercrL/8/))
Replace the right margin from `.section25` and `.section75`

### CSS

```
.section75 {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%; }

.section25 {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 25%; }
```

Comment: w3schools.com is an [unreliable source](http://www.w3fools.com/) and should be avoided.

Comment: @Borodin I know. Does it invalidate my answer, or is it just a general statement?